# How to react to camera events in android

Tags: android, service, camera

I want to make an app and in this app i want to save all the user taken images like this:

- user takes picture with default camera app
- my app give a notification it has succesfully backed up the image

Is there a way i can see the event of the camera app? and use this in my service?

I tryied searching for it on google and cant find anything

im trying to get to in with a service running in the background of my application

i know i need to import the camera classes

Answer (score 0):

Hi You are able to cature the Image From this Example Url:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/

And also You are able to Make a Notification that The Captured Image are saved in the Location.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

> user takes picture with default camera app

There are ~1.5 billion Android devices, spanning thousands of device models, with hundreds of "default camera app" implementations. There are also hundreds more camera apps that the user might install through the Play Store or other channels.

> my app give a notification it has succesfully backed up the image

There is no requirement that your app have the ability to access the image, wherever it gets stored. For example, the camera app might upload it directly to a Web service, or might store it on removable storage.

> Is there a way i can see the event of the camera app?

There is no documented protocol, let alone a requirement to follow it, where camera apps let arbitrary third party apps know that a picture was taken.

> i know i need to import the camera classes

Only if you are going to write your own camera app.